# Why doesn't the expression "[^\\w]+" produce a string of consecutive charracters that are the same as first character?

Tags: java, regex

Example strings : "ttttar", "bbbb abbb", "cccacc bbb"

I want to extract "tttt", "bbbb" and "ccc" respectively using expression [^\\w]+

I know for sure that ^\\w produces the very first char of each string. So then shouldn't the resulting expression be [t]+ , for first string, and hence evaluated to "tttt"?

Comment: You need a backreference, `^(\w)\1*`, or in Java, `"^(\\w)\\1*"`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`[^\w]+`](https://regex101.com/r/GfBKbo/1) (equal to `\W+`) pattern matches one or more chars other than word chars anywhere inside a string. It happens so because `[^...]` is a [***negated character class***](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any char BUT the one(s) specified inside the class.

You may use

```
^(\w)\1*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7LT5t/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w)` - Group 1: any word char
- `\1*` - 0+ occurrences of the char captured in Group 1

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/slJhHu):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("ttttar","bbbb abbb","cccacc bbb");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w)\\1*");
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(str + ": " + m.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ttttar: tttt
bbbb abbb: bbbb
cccacc bbb: ccc
```

Comment: Hi, thanks!
But can you tell me why my way of thinking doesn't work.  What exactly did I go wrong? It bothers me.

Comment: @AungKhant The [`[^\w]+`](https://regex101.com/r/GfBKbo/1) (equal to `\W+`) pattern matches one or more chars other than word chars anywhere inside a string. It happens so because `[^...]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any char BUT the one(s) specified inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

First, you put the `^` in the wrong place. You have put it inside the `[]`, which makes it mean something completely different. `[^]` denotes a reverse character class, so it matches anything that is *not* in the character class. You should put it outside of the `[]`.

Another thing is that you seem to want to match the *same* character consecutively, for that you can't just use a simple character class. You need a back reference. Regex does not work in the way you described, unfortunately.

```
^(\w)\1*
```

Note that I put `\w` into a group, specifically, group 1. And I only match that once. Then, I match `\1`, which means "what I group 1 contains".

Comment: Aah, I was aware that ^ have a different thing, but just thought that the expression ^\\w inside was executed first. Thanks!